# ARM.Template from bash-script. Unterminated string. Expected delimiter:

Tags: json, linux, bash, shell

I am writing a bash-script for uploading certificate from a linux-server to azure keyvault using the "armclient"

I follow this guide on how to use the armclient:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2016/05/24/deploying-azure-web-app-certificate-through-key-vault/

The command i want to perform is this:

```
ARMClient.exe PUT /subscriptions/<Subscription Id>/resourceGroups/<Server Farm Resource Group>/providers/Microsoft.Web/certificates/<User Friendly Resource Name>?api-version=2016-03-01 "{'Location':'<Web App Location>','Properties':{'KeyVaultId':'<Key Vault Resource Id>', 'KeyVaultSecretName':'<Secret Name>', 'serverFarmId':'<Server Farm (App Service Plan) resource Id>'}}"
```

I have created a string that populates all the fields required:

```
putparm=$resolved_armapi" \"{'Location':'$resolved_locationid','Properties':{'KeyVaultId':'$resolved_keyvaultid','KeyVaultSecretName':'$certname','serverFarmId':'$resolved_farmid'}}"\"
```

When i echo the output of the variable putparm, the result looks as expected (X-ed out names/ids):

```
/subscriptions/f073334f-240f-4261-9db5-XXXXXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/XXXXXXXX/providers/Microsoft.Web/certificates/XXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX?api-version=2016-03-01 "{'Location':'Central US','Properties':{'KeyVaultId':'/subscriptions/f073334f-240f-4261-9db5-XXXXXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/XXXXXXXX/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/XXXXXXXX','KeyVaultSecretName':'XXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX','serverFarmId':'/subscriptions/f073334f-240f-4261-9db5-XXXXXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/XXXXXXXX/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/ServicePlan59154b1c-XXXX'}}"
```

When i run `armclient put $putparm` in the script i get this error:

> "error": {
>       "code": "InvalidRequestContent",
>       "message": "The request content was invalid and could not be deserialized: 'Unterminated string. Expected delimiter: \". Path '',
>   line 1, position 21.'."   }

But when i take the output of the $putparm variable and run the command "manually" on the server, it works.

I guess its something with the way linux store the variables and that the API is requesting JSON (or something..)

Happy for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you define your variable `putparam` is wrong.

It is likely interpreted as a literal string and not as an object. Note that a simple string, like `"hello"`, is a valid JSON data, but it probably not what is expecting your server.

If you should quote your variable correctly:

```
putparm="{\"Location\":\"$resolved_locationid\",\"Properties\":{\"KeyVaultId\":\"$resolved_keyvaultid\",\"KeyVaultSecretName\":\"$certname\",\"serverFarmId\":\"$resolved_farmid\"}}"
```

and use it like this:

```
armclient put "$resolved_armapi" "$putparm"
```

Comment: yes, have identified problem with the JSON. The problem is that i dont know how to solve it. The quotation you posted didnt work either (same error). I got it to work when i used this https://www.freeformatter.com/json-formatter.html to convert my string. And paste that in a Json-file.

Comment: Without knowing what your tool `armclient` actually expects, it's a bit of try a error... You could at least quote your variable and use it like this `armclient put "$putparm"` and also try single quote around the json data like `putparm="$resolved_armapi '{...}'"`

Comment: @Fredrik actually it would be much better to call the tool like `armclient put "$resolved_armapi" "$putparm"` where `$putparm` only contains json data

Comment: This was what i ended up doing. I created a json-template file where i swapped out the variables and sent that to the armclient.

Comment: @Fredrik thanks for the feedback, i updated the answer